# Why anything done on comments_array hook gets reset?

Tags: filters, hooks, comments, sort

I am writing a plugin that will allow simple comment upvoting.

I am trying to sort comments by the number of upvotes. But anything I do on the comments_array Hook gets somehow reset. My question is where and how?

Here is my code:

```
add_filter( 'comments_array', 'biiird_order_comments_by_likes' );
function biiird_order_comments_by_likes( $array ) {

    $arraya = $array;

    usort($arraya, function($a, $b) {
        $likes_a = get_comment_meta( $a->comment_ID, 'likes', true );
        $likes_b = get_comment_meta( $b->comment_ID, 'likes', true );
        
        return ($likes_a > $likes_b) ? -1 : 1;

    });

    foreach ( $arraya as $comment ) {
        $comment->comment_content .= 'something';
    }
    var_dump($arraya);
    var_dump($array);

    return $arraya;
}
```

The `var_dump($arraya)` outputs a modified array in the proper order, but the comments show on a page as if the filter was not run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a bug.

If you look at the comment starting at [line 2100 of wp/wp-includes/comment-template.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/f0ac0275e8002ce7179209c811ed49635d277eac/wp-includes/comment-template.php#L2099-L2102) in the `wp_list_comments` function, you'll see that if the `per_page` argument is set and its value is different to that of the main wp_query, it'll perform a separate comment query and display those, instead of the ones you have sorted.

To get around this you'll need to create a custom walker and pass that to the `wp_list_comments` function and perform the sorting there:

```
wp_list_comments(['walker' => new MySortingCommentWalker()]);
```

Given that you are writing a plugin, you could use the `wp_list_comments_args` filter to ensure your custom walker is always used:

```
add_filter('wp_list_comments_args', function($args) {
    $args['walker'] = new MySortingCommentWalker();
    return $args;
});
```

You could extend the default `Walker_Comment` class, override the `paged_walk` method and sort the comments in there. Once sorted you can pass them to the parent method:

```
class MySortingCommentWalker extends \Walker_Comment
{
    public function paged_walk($elements, $max_depth, $page_num, $per_page, ...$args)
    {
        // Pass $elements to your sorting function here
        
        return parent::paged_walk($elements, $max_depth, $page_num, $per_page, $args);
    }
}
```

Comment: wow, Thanks! Do you maybe have a recommendation for someone (maybe you) who would like to mentor me in wp dev? I am willing to pay for 15min video mentoring a week. I am looking for someone, but people I asked so far say that they don't know how to explain/teach. (I also removed my bug report)

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found a bug in wordpress, the thing that is causing the problem is the `'per_page'` argument passed in `wp_list_comments()`. If it is set, then changes made to comments_array hook get reset or omitted later in the wp core.

I am 90% sure it's a bug and I have reported it on [wordpress trac](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/51537).